# Saving a post ID to use in a form elsewhere on website

Tags: php, posts, query-posts

I am trying to save a certain queried post's ID to pass on in a form outside of my loop.

To be more specific. I have one file named **review.php**, this file contains a Wordpress Loop which queries one post at a time. In my **sidebar.php** I have a form setup which will only display if the user is currently on the **review.php** page.

This form should pass along the queried post's ID from **review.php** in a hidden field. This ID will later be used to make changes to that post after form submission. (It's a reviewing system for posts)

How do I store the post's ID in **review.php** so that I can later echo it in my **sidebar.php**?

Answer (score 1):

save the id in a variable like this way

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

now you can use this $post_id variable in the hidden field.

Comment: This does not work, I have already tried doing so. I placed the line $post_id = get_the_id(); inside of my loop and then placed echo $post_id; in my sidebar.php which returned nothing.

Comment: Use global $post_id; in sidebar.php file

Comment: I had been adding global to the variable in my review.php and not sidebar.php @_@ Thank you :)